# (PHP) Evaluating simple logical expression

Tags: php

I have an expression in the following form (EBNF):

```
<expression> ::= ["("]<base>[")"][{<modifier>"("<expression>")"}]
<base>       ::= <logical>[{<modifier><logical>}]
<logical>    ::= "1" | "0"
<modifier>   ::= "&" | "|"
```

An example of a string in this format would be:

```
(1|(1&0))|(1&(1|0))
```

Or alternatively I can get this in postfix notation:

```
110&|110|&|
```

Is there an easy way, in PHP, to evaluate this? (i.e. the result for this particular example should be `1`). I want to avoid using `eval` function due to security issues.

If there isn't an easy way to achieve this in PHP without `eval` function, what would be the best approach for writing a custom parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy to achieve in PHP without the eval function.

You're going to have to use preg_match or something like it to evaluate your code and then convert it.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using RegEx to validate the code to ensure it's not  in correct format and thus safe and `eval` to then validate it - hopefully this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use eval. 
For getting around the security issue, you might set up a whitelist: 
$whitelist = array('(',')','1','0','%','|');

Best approach for writing a parser would be to get a parser generator like 
"loco" or "lime" or "php-peg". You simply define your grammar and start parsing it, either
using RegexpParser or StringParser (or both).
http://qntm.org/loco - http://qntm.org/files/loco/Loco.php

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already a correct answer, but there's a PHP parser for EBNF [here](http://karmin.ch/ebnf/index#ebnfphp)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have decided to take different approach - purely because of the fact that my code needs to be simple and efficient but it's good to know about the parser - will come in handy in the feature :)